# Button doesn't fully stick to bottom of screen in constraint layout

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-button

I constrain a button to the bottom of the screen, but unfortunately there is a small gap between the bottom border of the screen and the bottom border of the buttom:

[image]

My XML:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigationTabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabMinWidth="100dp"
        app:tabRippleColor="@null"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="BUTTON"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/navigationTabs" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What causes this gap? And how can I get rid of it?

Comment: there have a feature of android studio named "layout inspect". you can find it under tools option. you can inspect the layout using this feature to check what is causing the gap! hope if helps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the shadow around the button of the default background. Specify your own background and the gap will disappear. 
For example:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="#A4ABA4"
    android:text="BUTTON"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this code to **`<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ...>`** and **`<button ...>`**:

```
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:padding="0dp"
```

add this code to **`<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout ...>`** and **`<LinearLayout ...>`** and **`<button ...>`**:

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
```

add this code to **`<button ...>`**:

```
android:background="#c0c0c0"
```